# Using ng-click to show divs in Angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show

So I have a link in an html box and when clicking the link iam trying to have it show a whole new set of divs replacing the present divs.
I tried :

```
<a href="" ng-click="Search('Show Products A B C')" > Show Products </a>
```

Search calls in the function in the controller which returns the data for the A B C products, which are then displayed using

```
<div ng-repeat="products in Search( 'Show Products A B C')" </div>
```

I am basically trying to do something like this:

```
  <div  ng-repeat=" href="" ng-click="Search('Show Products A B C')"> </div>
```

which is not proper syntax I understand.
But right now nothing happens.
Basically from that ng-click i would like to call that portion of the code (ng-repeat) because right now they are not connected.
thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking about. Please, describe the problem clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is to have some **array or object A** bound to **$scope**, then when you call search you **update A** and the **changes will be reflected on your view**

```
$scope.show=true;
$scope.products =[A,B,C];
$scope.Search = function() {
    // do list update
    $scope.show=false;
    $scope.products =[D,E,F] ;
}
```

You also need to change ng-repeat to this:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products" </div>
```

And add ng-show to the first link:

```
<a href="#" ng-show = "show" ng-click="search();">Click Me</a>
```

Edit:

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/garurvve/) for a working example.

Edit:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/garurvve/1/) updated reflecting latest changes.

Comment: thank you, perhaps i did not explain my question well. so the issue is this, the link needs to be present, and so, i need to be able to click that link which is already in a div, and subsequently, the div products appear, and this div goes away.

Comment: @uniXVanXcel I edited the response and added a link to a JS Fiddle showing a working example based on the response given.

Comment: thanks your Fiiddle is not showing actually..I edited the question as well to make it more understandable

Comment: @uniXVanXcel Here it is. Hope this helps.


https://jsfiddle.net/garurvve/

Comment: That is exactly what I proposed @Maximo, great Job. uniXVanXcel you can make the first link disappear by addin a boolean B to the scope and use the ng-show attribute on the link. So when you call Search you set B to false. I will add thatt to my answer

Comment: @Maximo could you also update the fiddle with the new info?

Comment: @AbsalonCastañon All set. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`ng-repeat` will respond to changes in its argument, but your argument is a function `Search()`.  I would suggest the following:
In your search function:

```
$scope.Search = function(arg) {
    // do your search logic
    $scope.productList = <search result list>
}
```

then in html

```
<div ng-repeat="products in productList" </div>
```

Comment: thank you, perhaps i did not explain my question well. so the issue is this, the link needs to be present, and so, i need to be able to click that link which is already in a div, and subsequently, the div products appear, and this div goes away.